# Java number of results generated

Tags: java

Why this code generate 7 results while it should be 6 results?

```
public class Testowanie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
        while (x < 10) {
            x = x + 1;
            if (x > 3) {
                System.out.println("Wielkie X");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `x = 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`, they are 7 results. They should be 7, not 6, what makes you think they are 6? I recommend you to debug by hand or use a debugger

Comment: I expect what you are looking for is `if (x > 3 && x < 10)` then you would get the result you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

1 to 10 , if (x > 3) match for [4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

The probleme here it's probably where you increment your x, try to put it at the end, you will get 6 results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int x = 1;
while (x < 10) {

    if (x > 3) {
        System.out.println("Wielkie X");
    }
    x = x + 1;

}
```

}

To be more precise, when you start your while loop with x = 3, first you're incrementing x (x = 4), so you print your text despite your started your loop with x = 3. 
And so on until 9, at 9 you start your loop, increment x (x = 10) pass your condition (x > 3) and print. It was your last loop, x value is now 10. So you print from 3 to 10, easy math 10-3 = 7